# Return в цикле Python возвращает none

Tags: python, математика

```
def digital_root(n): #складывает цифры у числа
    n=str(n)
    if len(str(n))>1:
        n=sum(int(i) for i in n)
        digital_root(n)
    else:
        return n
print(digital_root(1443)) #None
```

Return не хочет внутри цикла выводить значение переменной. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему это так. и как это исправить.

Comment: м. б. перед else все-таки `return digital_root(n)`,  а не просто `digital_root(n)`?

Comment: В рекурсии всегда должно быть как минимум два return!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот код с исправлениями(проверено)

```
def digital_root(n): #складывает цифры у числа
        n=str(n)
        if len(n)>=2:
            n=sum(int(i) for i in n)
            return digital_root(n)
        elif len(n)==1:
            return n
    print(digital_root(1443)) #None
```